# Absolute maximum calculus 3

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y) = (x -1)^2 + 3(y-2)^2$ and the region $R = \{(x,y) : y \leq x\}$. If it exists, find the absolute maximum of $f(x,y)$ on $R$. If it does not exist then say so.

I first found the partial derivatives of f and I got the critical point (1, 2). However, that is not in the region. So the next thing I tried was to check the boundary, but I wasn't sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The absolute maximum certainly does not exist because you can make $f$ arbitrarily large by making both $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily large (within $R$).  I have a feeling you're not posting the right question.  (Let $x \to 10^{100}$ and $y \to 10^{100} -1$)....

Comment: Hi. I did double check and I wrote the question out exactly as it was written by my instructor. Usually we have a region where we can find the boundary lines, but for this one the only region we are given is y is less than or equal to x.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute maximum certainly does not exist because you can make $$ arbitrarily large by making both $$ and $$ arbitrarily large (within $$). (Let $ \to 10^{100}$ and $y \to 10^{100}−1$)....

[image]

---

I have a feeling you're not posting the right question.

Comment: Hi. I did double check and I wrote the question out exactly as my instructor did.

Comment: Well then my answer is correct, and should be accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The boundary is $y=x$.  Plug it in.   We get $(x-1)^2+3(x-2)^2=4x^2-14x+13$.

This (polynomial) function is unbounded;  hence there's no max.